# Algebraic structure on a class

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, set-theory

Is there a group structure on a class instead of a set?

We know that all algebraic structures are defined on a set. It is important the possibility of defining a group structure or a ring structure in a class.

Comment: Yes, such "groups" exist. You can also ask for more. As an example: the surreal numbers even form a class-sized ordered field.

Comment: Consider the symmetric difference on the class of all sets.

Comment: Another very important example is the (large) semiring of all cardinal numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The important thing here is that given two classes $A$, $B$, it is possible to describe a "class function" from $A$ to $B$ as a class $F \subseteq A \times B$ such that $\forall a \in A \exists! b \in B ((a, b) \in F)$.

Once we have class functions, we can define a "class group" as a class $A$, together with a class function $\_ \cdot \_ : A^2 \to A$ that satisfies the usual group axioms.

Comment: Mark, I need a constructed example for the ring. If it is simple to define some algebraic structure then why it is not used in mathematics.

Comment: @alireza: It is used (see the surreal numbers, for example). It is not used often because it's not usually something we need, and working with proper classes does present a few complications (since you need to always verify that you can do the things you want to do).